Solving $2abx^2+(a-b)^2x-(a^2+b^2)=0$
How do I get to the solution set of this equation?
$$2abx^2+(a-b)^2x-(a^2+b^2)=0$$
Apparently, it should be solved by quadratic formula, and its answer set is $\left\{1;-\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{ab}\right\}$
When I try to solve it, I get stuck on the quadratic with
$$\frac{-(a-b)^2+\sqrt{(a-b)^4-4(2ab)(a^2+b^2)}}{2(2ab)}$$
which then for me turns into
$$\frac{-a^2+2ab-b^2+\sqrt{a^4-12a^3b+6a^2b^2-12ab^3+b^4}}{4ab}$$
but as I keep expanding I have no idea how to reach those said solutions or if the method is even the correct one

Apparently, we're supposed to solve for $x$ (which isn't in your problem statement).  What happens when you try to solve this quadratic in $x$ for $x$?

Are you familiar with the concept of "polynomial division" ?

\begin{align*}
2abx^{2} + (a - b)^{2}x - (a^{2} + b^{2}) & = (2abx^{2} - 2abx) + (a^{2} + b^{2})(x - 1)\
& = 2abx(x - 1) + (a^{2} + b^{2})(x - 1)
\
& = (2abx + a^{2} + b^{2})(x - 1)
\end{align*}

It's easy to check that $1$ is a root, and the product of the two eoots is $-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}.$ So your answer is wrong.

"I know nothing" is an unbiased, ideal starting point. Start from the solution: $u(x-v)(x-w)$ is $0$ for $\left{x=v;x=w\right}$. Multiplying the ansatz gives $ux^2-ux(v+w)+uvw$. Now compare the single terms with your equation. HTH

This question of yours reads like a Do-My-Homework-For-Me, which makes many of us salty. This question of yours also goes against the MSE Guidelines. Can't you at least write down the quadratic formula and your attempts at using it.

Hi, I thought i had to use quadratic formula as that's the topic which I was looking at before doing this exercise, I can see how to solve it with polynomial division which is a great help. I'm sorry I just got stuck at every attempt at using quadratic formula so possibly the best procedure for this is just polynomial division

Please (again) edit your post to show us at least one of these failed attempts to use the quadratic formula.

It looks like you rendered tge discriminant as $(a-b)^2+4ab(a^2+b^2)$. But it's actually $[(a-b)^2]^{\color{blue}{2}}+4ab(a^2+b^2)$. You have a square in the linear coefficient and then that whole thing has to be squared again in the discriminant. You should then be able to equate the square root of the discriminant with $(a+b)^2$, after which everything is easy to simplify.

Forget the quadratic formula for this equation. Instead note that when you expand $(a-b)^2$ you get $(a^2+b^2)-2ab.$ These two terms are exactly the coefficients of the other terms in the equation. You can then group terms by coefficient and easily factor the equation. Look at @ÁtilaCorreia's comment above!

There are two mistakes in your solution to the quadratic equation. It should be $$\frac{-(a-b)^2\color{red}{\pm}\sqrt{(a-b)^4\color{red}{+}4(2ab)(a^2+b^2)}}{2(2ab)}$$

And  it simplfies to $\frac{-(a-b)^2\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^4}}{4ab}.$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+2abx%5E2%2B%28a%E2%88%92b%29%5E2x-%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%29%3D0

Expanding $(a-b)^2$ we get $(a^2+b^2)-2ab,$ two terms that we find in other places in the equation. Collecting terms by $(a^2+b^2)$ and $2ab$ we can easily factor the quadratic:
$$\begin{align}
2abx^2+(a-b)^2x-(a^2+b^2)
&= 2abx^2+((a^2+b^2)-2ab)x-(a^2+b^2) \\
%&= (2abx^2-2abx)+((a^2+b^2)x-(a^2+b^2)) \\
&= 2abx(x-1)+(a^2+b^2)(x-1) \\
&= (2abx+(a^2+b^2))(x-1)
\end{align}$$
Now you should be able to directly solve the equation.

In case you need help, as the comments say:
$$
x=\frac{-(a-b)^2\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^4}}{4ab}=\frac{-(a-b)^2\pm(a+b)^2}{4ab}
$$
Taking $+$ first, we get:
$$x=\frac{-(a-b)^2+(a+b)^2}{4ab}=\frac{4ab}{4ab}=1$$
and again, taking $-$ first, we get:
$$
x=\frac{-(a-b)^2-(a-b)^2}{4ab}=\frac{-2(a^2+b^2)}{4ab}=-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}
$$
If you feel confused about the expansion of the discriminant, here is the step:
$$(a-b)^4+4(2ab)(a^2+b^2)$$
$$=\left((a-b)^2\right)^2+4(2ab)(a^2+b^2)$$
$$=(a+b)^4$$
where, I am used the formula $(x+y)^2=(x-y)^2-4xy$, taking $y=2ab$ and $x=a^2+b^2$, that makes $(x-y)=a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2$ and $(x+y)=a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$
Hope this helps.

We have,
$2abx^2+(a-b)^2x-(a^2+b^2)=0$
Which can be rearranged as
$2abx^2+(a^2+b^2)x-2abx-(a^2+b^2)=0$
$\implies$
$2abx(x-1)+(a^2+b^2)(x-1)=0$
$\implies$
$(x-1)(2abx+a^2+b^2)=0$
Therefore, either
$x-1=0 \implies x=1$ or
$2abx+a^2+b^2=0 \implies x= \frac{a^2+b^2}{-2ab} $
Hence, the roots will be
$(1, \frac{a^2+b^2}{-2ab}) $

Here my "braindead recipe solving quadratic formulas in easy digestable chunks":
Start from the solution with its answer set $\left\{v;\ w\right\}$
$$u(x-v)(x-w)=0{,}\ u\ne 0\tag{1}$$
expanding it, omitting the implicit $=0$, turns into
$$ux^2-u(v+w)x+uvw\tag{2}$$
Comparing its terms with the equation in OP (in respect of $x^2$, $x^1$, and $x^0$) shows
$$u=2ab\tag{3a}$$
$$-u(v+w)=(a-b)^2\tag{3b}$$
$$uvw=-(a^2+b^2)\tag{3c}$$
Now the "dirty trick" – two figures summed yield twice their arithmetic mean $m$, while both have the same distance $n$ to $m$. Thus
$$v=m+n\tag{4a}$$
$$w=m-n\tag{4b}$$
Add $(4a)$ and $(4b)$ results in
$$v+w=2m\tag{5}$$
solved for $m$
$$m=\frac{v+w}{2}\tag{5a}$$
Multiply $(4a)$ and $(4b)$ results in
$$vw=m^2-n^2\tag{6}$$
since "we know" $m$ already, see $(5a)$, solved for $n$
$$n=\sqrt{m^2-vw}\tag{6a}$$
With $(5a)$
$$n=\sqrt{\left (\frac{v+w}{2}\right )^2-vw}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{v^2+2vw+w^2}{4}-\frac{4vw}{4}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{v^2-2vw+w^2}{4}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\left (\frac{v-w}{2}\right )^2}$$
$$=\frac{v-w}{2}\tag{6b}$$
Intentionally I omit here $\pm$ as possible solutions of the sqare root, it would only double the results of $(4a)$ and $(4b)$ with $v_2=w_1$ and vice versa.
Substitute $(5a)$ and $(6b)$ in $(4a)$
$$v=\frac{v+w}{2}+\frac{v-w}{2}$$
Similar for $(4b)$ – well, it's nothing new, it is the ansatz $(1)$.
Back to the equation in OP.
$(5)$ in $(3b)$
$$-u(2m)=(a-b)^2$$
solved for $m$ and respecting $(3a)$ (since $u\ne 0$ it's possible to divide by $u$)
$$m=\frac{(a-b)^2}{-4ab}\tag{5b}$$
$(6)$ in $(3c)$
$$u(m^2-n^2)=-(a^2+b^2)$$
solved for $n$ and respecting $(3a)$
$$n=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}+m^2}$$
also respecting $(5b)$
$$n=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}+\left (\frac{(a-b)^2}{-4ab}\right )^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4}{16a^2b^2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^4}{16a^2b^2}}$$
$$=\frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}\tag{6c}$$
$(5b)$ and $(6c)$ in $(4a)$
$$v=\frac{(a-b)^2}{-4ab}+\frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}$$
$$=-\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{4ab}+\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4ab}$$
$$=1$$
$(5b)$ and $(6c)$ in $(4b)$
$$w=\frac{(a-b)^2}{-4ab}-\frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}$$
$$=-\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{4ab}-\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4ab}$$
$$=-\frac{2a^2+2b^2}{4ab}$$
$$=-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}$$ — and we are done :)
